# Should I get a downhill bike a little bit smaller size?

Tags: mountain-bike, size, downhill

My question would be is if I should buy a YT Tues CF 27.5 2017, size M when my height is 181cm, and the bike's chart goes up to 178 cm. And it is used by the way.

Comment: The only practical answer is for you to go try it.   Getting a leg over the bike will tell you if its comfortable or not.  Ideally take it for a test ride, if the seller permits.

Comment: Depending on your skill level (if you're a DH novice) a slightly too small frame may increase your confidence as you may feel more in control.

Comment: A smaller frame will lower your centre of gravity and most likely increase you stability.